# 3d delaunay triangulation with given set of points

Tags: c++, cgal

I need some help with 3d tetrahedralization. I have many points in a cube with x,y,z coordinates, and i want to create a delaunay mesh with them, and get the tetrahedras of this mesh.
I tried to search for libraries, and i found cgal, but i just cant understand how it works, and how to solve this problem in it, ive seen the examples too, but i didnt found example for 3d delaunay triangulation. Can anybody help me with this, how to solve this problem with cgal, or with any other library? Im using c++.
Thank you.

Comment: How about [this example](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.2/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_3/Chapter_main.html#Section_22.6). Can you just plug in your points into this example?

Comment: Yes, this is sth i was searching for, i just skipped it somehow. So, with Triangulation_3 class i can do the tetrahedralization, it will generate the triangles or tetrahedras which nodes are my points, right? Then only one quession left, how get i the tetrahedras of the  Triangulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the  [finite cells iterator](http://doc.cgal.org/4.2/CGAL.CGAL.3D-Triangulations/html/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__3.html#a918fb95483ba224caa0fcb9654afe905)

(or the all cells iteraor if you want also the convex hull facets)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was searching for. And thanks for sietschie for the examples i needed.

Comment: i almost done the problem, but sth missing. If i use the iterator and the tetrahedron() method, i got coordinates, not the indicies of the vertices, is there any way to get the indicies instead of the coordinates ?